# black screen with every browser on page http://ahead.com

Tags: browser

I use Chromium, Firefox and even IE, but http://ahead.com gives me a black screen, no error message, nothing....

Comment: the site appears to have some fault ,it wont load, try later

Comment: @Shark It worked when I answered, and it works now. Mac OS X, Safari 4, ClickToFlash.

Answer (score 2):

It's a Flash page. Have you installed Adobe Flash? If yes, try right-clicking the page to see if the menu refers to an unloaded Flash movie. You might need to wait a while while it loads.

Comment: i use newest chromium, 10.0 something, should have flash build in, right click gives me about flash 10 and on the first line something like move not loaded. (it's not in english)

Comment: It is a flash page , try right clicking on the page . Download the latest flash plugin both ie and non ie variants and install them .

Comment: You have version 10,1,102,64 installed.  could it be a proxy problem? but in this case, normaly I get an error from the proxy, not showing the content.

Comment: @browser Some Flash problems stem from wrong paths to the Flash files that work in some browsers only. Is it still a problem in all browsers, even with newest Flash on all of them?